# Merge bezier curves without deformation?

Tags: mesh, groups

So I've been working on the hair of a character, and I need to merge all the hair strips together. But whenever I do that, everything is deformed after doing so. I have tried applying rotation and scale, but this also deforms the hair.
[image: Before joining]

[image: After joining]

Comment: I just needed to convert the curve into a mesh.

Comment: Ah :-) so, delete the question?